# Git cloning error

Tags: networking, git

I've just started to learn git and I tried to run this command :

```
git clone git://github.com/schacon/ticgit.git
```

> It did not work and I got this error message

```
gwapps@gwapps-ThinkPad-X61:/home/gitRepo$ sudo git clone git://github.com/schacon/ticgit.git
Cloning into 'ticgit'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 204.232.175.90]: errno=Connection refused
```

Is there anyone who can help me the solve this problem ? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
 output of netstat -tulpn

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 10.20.2.160:123         0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44048           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 fe80::216:d3ff:fec4:123 :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::58657                :::*     

                       -
```

Comment: Are you running a firewall?

Comment: @Mitch Nope, but now I'm in the company and maybe they're running ?

Comment: Add the output of command `netstat -tulpn`

Comment: @Tarun I added it

Comment: As expected Mitch is correct git uses port number 9418 by default and that I can't see in the above output of `netstat -tulpn` you need to open that port.

Comment: @Tarun how could you understand the port is not opened ?

Comment: look in the ouput of the above command can you see any port `9418` like `127.0.0.1:123` shows port no `123` is open on your local machine. I don't see it, this is because it is not open.

Comment: okey got it,sorry for the basic questions I'm really newbie in this area and very greathful for your valuable comments

Answer (score 8):

Run `git clone http://github.com/schacon/ticgit.git` instead.

That is, replace `git://` with `http://`. This should work.

For an encrypted connection--which is generally a good thing because the data you receive probably cannot be modified in transit by any malicious third party--you can try using `https://`. *Thanks to Mitch for [pointing this out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333343/git-cloning-error/333358?noredirect=1#comment424473_333358).* This worked for me, though it was considerably slower (it took almost half a minute instead of less than two seconds). Your mileage may vary.

Explanation follows... (But if you want, you can stop reading here and just use that command.)

#### Your corporate (or school) network *might* be preventing you from accessing the Git server.

On my Internet connection, I've checked to see if the IP address 204.232.175.90 has a server accepting incoming connections on port 9418. (After all, that is what *it* has to do, not what *you* have to do.) It does, though at that time (i.e., before I tried cloning the repo myself) it was not clear to me if what's running on that port is actually a Git server:

```
ek@Kip:~$ sudo nmap -sS -sV -p9418 204.232.175.90
[sudo] password for ek:

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-08-16 09:25 EDT
Nmap scan report for github.com (204.232.175.90)
Host is up (0.046s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
9418/tcp open  domain  ISC BIND   Email support

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.82 seconds
```

Even if that had been something other than a Git server, you should still not have gotten "connection refused". If you get the same error when you try again, *something* is blocking your ability to connect to that server. If possible, I recommend consulting your network administrator. After all, you *should* ideally be able to access that server. And most network administrators are probably not going to have a problem with you accessing Git repositories.

#### However, there is an easy workaround.

For people in your situation, and other situations where only HTTP access is possible (for example, people whose only access to the Internet is through an HTTP proxy), Git provides the ability to access repositories with HTTP (i.e., via the web)!

I *don't* mean that you'd browse the web to clone the repository. The `git` command is itself capable of connecting over HTTP, as an alternative to using Git's own application layer protocol.

To do this, replace `git://` with `http://` in the URL given to the `git` command.

From your perspective as a user, this works exactly the same way. The only difference you may notice (besides that this way should work!) is that it may be *slower*, since HTTP is less well-suited to accessing Git repositories than Git's own protocol.

That can be an issue over time, or for huge repositories. That's why I recommend contacting your network administrator. But in this case, there should be no problems; the repository appears small. (Even if it were large, increased wait times are sometimes acceptable. It's when you have to transfer a lot of data, many times per day, that it can become burdensome to your workflow.)

It's possible for a Git server *not* to offer HTTP access, but in practice that is rare, and *I have tested this one, and it does provide it, and I was able to clone the repository*:

```
ek@Kip:~/src$ git clone http://github.com/schacon/ticgit.git
Cloning into 'ticgit'...
remote: Counting objects: 1857, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1022/1022), done.
remote: Total 1857 (delta 781), reused 1787 (delta 735)
Receiving objects: 100% (1857/1857), 374.78 KiB | 702 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (781/781), done.
ek@Kip:~/src$ ls ticgit                # you don't have to run this
bin       lib          LICENSE_MIT  Rakefile    spec               TODO
examples  LICENSE_GPL  note         README.mkd  ticgit-ng.gemspec
ek@Kip:~/src$ du -sh ticgit            # you don't have to run this
844K    ticgit
```

I also did it with `git://` and got the same results. HTTP access works fine for this repository.

As stated above, `https://` worked fine for me too, though it was much slower. But I think a lot of the time may have been in negotiating the connection--I don't expect that it would necessarily be much slower than `http://` for a large repository.

Comment: What about `https://github.com/schacon/ticgit.git`?

Comment: @Mitch Good call. I've expanded my answer to cover this.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you may have a network issue.  git protocol uses the port 9418 by default, so make sure that the port is open, and not blocked by a firewall.

Comment: how could I detect it ? @Mitch

Comment: @Mitch A Git *server* (typically) listens on port 9418. Some corporate firewalls do block *outgoing connections* based on port (and that could be happening here), but it's unlikely any residential ISP does this (unless there's some country where Git is illegal... :), and port 9418 doesn't have to be open in the sense of being accessible from the outside (e.g., port-forwarded through a NAT router, `iptables` set to accept incoming connections on it) just to clone a Git repo.

Comment: @EliahKagan so, how could I detect 9418 is whether open or blocked ??

Comment: @EliahKagan What do you suggest?  The OP did mention that he is at work, and they might have a firewall running.

Comment: Mitch, @Eday Just tell the `git` command to use HTTP instead. [I've posted an answer.](http://askubuntu.com/a/333358/22949)