# Git error: unable to connect to "..."

Tags: networking, proxy, git

I am running a VM with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and tried this command:
It's from the [yocto documentation](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/mega-manual/mega-manual.html) and so I guess it isn't wrong.

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
```

And get following error:

```
Cloning into 'poky'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.yoctoproject.org:
git.yoctoproject.org: Name or service not known
```

The git server seems to be online when I access the site via browser. However,
I found two topics on the site with a similar problem:

- ["git.osmocom.org: Name or service not known" while cloning osmocom.org repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/528025/448613)

> No solution, because I have Internet connection inside the VM

- [Git cloning error](https://askubuntu.com/q/333343/448613)

> Tried both http:// and https://, but it didn't work.

What I assume is, that the problem is associated with the usage of a proxy, but I don't know what to enter:

All Settings >> Network >> Network proxy:

> Method: Manual
>
> HTTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1  ;Port: 3128
>
> HTTPS Proxy: 127.0.0.1  ;Port: 3128
>
> FTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1  ;Port: 3128
>
> Socks Host: empty ;Port: empty

(Can't post screenshot!)

---

BTW:

```
user:~$     git --version
             git version 1.9.1
```

Also tried multiple version with `sudo` , `sudo -s` etc...

---

The firewall seemed to be guilty, although 'the IT guys' assured GIT would work.

What helped, was to install 'socat' and to create a script 'gitproxy'

```
#!/bin/sh
_proxy=<proxyadress>
_proxyport=<port>

exec socat STDIO PROXY:$_proxy:$1:$2,proxyport=$_proxyport
```

And configure git with it:

```
$  git config --global core.gitProxy <path_to_script>
```

Solution found [here](http://www.emilsit.net/blog/archives/how-to-use-the-git-protocol-through-a-http-connect-proxy/).

Comment: just tried to do it on my machine, and it worked ... - if it's for example your work network, ask IT guys :)

Comment: `ping git.yoctoproject.org`?